# redesign to accomodate this use case

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have various python machine learning models/classes that have the following class defs:

```
class Model(pl.LightningModule):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       # perform initialisation
```

I am using pytorch lightning which also allows one to create a model instance from a saved checkpoint.

For each class I provide a load method as:

```
@classpath
def load(cls, **kwargs):
    if "checkpoint_file" in kwargs:
        # call the class method provided by the parent
        return Model.load_from_checkpoint(kwargs["checkpoint_file"])
    else:
        return MyModel(**kwargs)
```

I need to do this for every class as I need to provide a single callable instansiator (due to use of facebook hydra). I was wondering if there is some design pattern I can utilise to not have to define this for every class.

Comment: I am not Python developer, however, can inheritance do what you want?

Comment: Issue is that it is a classmethod and not sure how to resolve the right class from it through inheritance